# Construction of the Sylvester graph

Tags: graph-theory

So I am currently reading up on the construction of the Sylvester graph.

Based on my readings, it is said that the Sylvester graph is construction from the generalised quadrangle GQ(2,2)

To construct the unique generalised quadrangle GQ(2,2) we consider the complete graph $K_6$. Taking its edges for the set of points $P$ and its complete matchings for the set of lines $L$.

Let an ovoid in a finite geometry be a subset of $P$ such that each line contains precisely one of its points. Then dually a spread is a subset of $L$ such that each point is on precisely one  of its lines.

To construct the Sylvester graph, one considers the 36 ordered  pairs (ovoid,spread) of $GQ(2,2)$ as vertices, with vertices $(O,S)$ and $(O',S')$ being adjacent if and only if $O\cap O'=\{p\}\subset P$, $S\cap S'=\{l\}\subset L$, and $p\in l$.

The obtained graph is called the Sylvester graph. It is 5-regular with diameter 3 and girth 5, such that for any vertex $x$ of the graph, the vertices  at distance 2 (resp 3) from $x$ induce a union of cycles (resp. a perfect matching).

The issue I have with the construction is that I can't seem to find any examples of ovoid or spread in the $GQ(2,2)$. Can somebody kindly give me an example of an ovoid and spread in the $GQ(2,2)$ as shown in the figure below.

Also, any assistance to why there are 36 pairs of (ovoid,spread) and why the graph is 5-regular will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: The blue dots and blue lines are example of an ovoid and a spread. There is another family of ovoids (but harder to catch). Can you spot it? It will give you 6 ovoids. Similarly, there are 6 spreads, so 36 pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geometry $GQ(2,2)$, a generalised quadrangle whose $15$ points are
the $2$-subsets of a $6$-set $X$ and whose $15$ lines are the partitions of $X$ into
$2$-subsets. If $X=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, then
points have the form $(ij)$ and the lines have the form $\{(ij),(kl),(mn)\}$,
where $i,j,k,l,m,n\in X$ are all distinct.

In the diagram of the graph $GQ(2,2)$ the lines are in three colors: black, blue, red

[image]

It has six ovoids, namely the six sets (of size $5$) consisting of all pairs containing a fixed symbol.
For instance one of the six ovoids $O_1=\{12,13,14,15,16\}$.

Also there are $6$ of spreads. Here is one of them, dual to the indicated ovoid:
$$S_1=\{
(12)(35)(46),
(13)(24)(56),
(14)(25)(36),
(15)(26)(34),
(16)(23)(45)\}.
$$

**Addition.**
Here is the complete list of spreads.
\begin{align*}
S_1&=\{(12)(35)(46),(13)(24)(56),(14)(25)(36),(15)(26)(34),(16)(23)(45)\},\\
S_2&=\{(12)(35)(46),(16)(25)(34),(13)(26)(45),(14)(23)(56),(15)(24)(36)\},\\
S_3&=\{(13)(24)(56),(16)(25)(34),(15)(23)(46),(12)(36)(45),(14)(26)(35)\},\\
S_4&=\{(14)(25)(36),(13)(26)(45),(15)(23)(46),(16)(24)(35),(12)(34)(56)\},\\
S_5&=\{(15)(26)(34),(14)(23)(56),(12)(36)(45),(16)(24)(35),(13)(25)(46)\},\\
S_6&=\{(16)(23)(45),(15)(24)(36),(14)(26)(35),(12)(34)(56),(13)(25)(46)\}.
\end{align*}
Note that any pair of different ovoids has exactly one common point and any pair of different spreads has exactly one common line. Let $O_1,S_1$ be a pair (ovoid, spread) where $O_1,S_1$ are introduced above.
Consider the ovoid $O_2=\{21,23,24,25,26\}$. We have $O_1\cap O_2=\{12\}$.
We have $O_1\cap O_2=\{12\}$ and the line $l=(12)(35)(46)\in S_1$ contains the point $(12)$.
We see that there is exactly one spread $S_2$, which contains the line $l$.

Similarly, for the ovoid $Q_3=\{31,32,34,35,36\}$ there is exactly one spread $S_3$, that
$S_3\cap S_1=\{(13)(24)(56)\}$ and $O_1\cap O_3=\{13\}$. And so on.

Thus there are exactly five pairs $(O_i,S_i)$, $i=2,\ldots,6$ adjacent to the pair $(O_1,S_1)$.

By virtue of symmetry, this is true for each pair $(O,S)$.

Comment: I see so there are 6 ovoids in total. What about the spreads? All the blue lines, and {56,23,14}, {13,46,25}, {12,45,36}, {15,34,26}, {35, 24,16} and it’s 5 symmetries. Am I right?

Comment: Also, may I know if there is any easy way to see why this graph is 5-regular?

Comment: The Sylvester graph is $5$-regular.

Comment: I meant why is it that each (ovoid, spread) pair is adjacent to 5 other (ovoid, spread) pair

Comment: @Explorer1234
I made an addition, which I hope helps to understand that the degree of each vertex of the Sylvester graph is $5$.

Comment: It did help alot. Thanks for putting in the time and effort (+1)